# Error in library(deSolve) : there is no package called ‘deSolve’

Tags: r, r-package

I used `install.packages("deSolve", dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')` to install the package, but it still says there's no package called deSolve

I tried `install.packages(deSolve)` and `install.packages("deSolve", dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')` but they are not working.
When I ran `install.packages(deSolve)` , the output is
`ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rootSolve’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/rootSolve’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rootSolve’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package ‘deSolve’ ...
  ** package ‘deSolve’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘deSolve’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/deSolve’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘deSolve’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependencies ‘deSolve’, ‘rootSolve’ are not available for package ‘FME’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/FME’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘FME’ had non-zero exit status
  `

Comment: The code to install packages in your first sentence is correct and should work. Can you install other packages?

Comment: You should show us the response after you called `install.packages(...)` and `library(deSolve)`; maybe we can tell you what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the package should be available for [install via CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/). Ensure you have a working internet connection and your firewall is not blocking installs. As an alternative, you can also try installing it [from Posit Package Manager](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/packages/overview?search=desolve). Setup instructions [here](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/setup).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the OP uses a Mac. If yes, then it may be a problem with the [Command Line Tools from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html). The following answers to related questions may help:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673827

I want to add, that it is not a specific deSolve problem, but a configuration problem of the operating system. In addition, it may be a good idea to upgrade to a recent version of R. The error messages indicate version R 4.1 while the most recent version is R 4.3.2.